# Get id of jQuery dialog and close it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to close a jQuery dialog displayed on a page under certain conditions if it is open.

I use the following selector to determine if a jQuery dialog is currently being displayed: `($(".ui-dialog").is(":visible"))`.  I thought I could use this same selector to actually get a reference to a dialog container object and call `.dialog('close')` on it, however this is not the case.  It seems that the selector returns a reference to the contained element of the dialog content and not the div dialog container.  How do I get the `id` of the dialog container and call close on it?

I ended up doing this:

`if ($(".ui-dialog").is(":visible")) {
    $(".ui-dialog").children('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
}`

Comment: If you keep track of what dialogs you actually opened, it should be trivial to close them again

Comment: @adeneo, this logic is being executed in an event.  I don't want to make the dialog references visible to the event, rather I want the event to look at the DOM and see if any dialogs are being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$( ".ui-dialog-content" ).dialog( "close" );`. It looks like that is the element that the dialog is attached to.

Comment: Yes, I took a closer look at the DOM and discovered this.  Looks like it creates a wrapper element with the `ui-dialog` class and the actual element the dialog is attached to is a child and tagged with `.ui-dialog-content`.

Answer (score 2):

If dialog is attached to .ui-dialog-content, you could do something like this as a test. Then, work on something which would scale.

```
<button id="close">close the dialog</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#close").click(function() {
        $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is open, you don't need to test it. When the user presses some button or click out of the modal dialog, you can just close it.

```
$('.ui-dialog').fadeOut();
```